# 'DeclareMathOperator' is not working with subscripts or superscripts

Tags: bug, status-review, mathjax

Somehow SE's MathJax doesn't like `\DeclareMathOperator` in subscripts or superscripts. This doesn't render on SE:

```tex
$\DeclareMathOperator{\two}{two}$
$\two+\two=\two^\two$
```

(I can't directly demonstrate the failure here, since MathJax seems not available in this community.)

But in the [MathJax demo](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) it renders just fine:

[image]

What's the reason?  Different version of MathJax?

Comment: Is it related to the [scoping change](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4130)? Can you reproduce it in the [Math sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/370)?

Comment: @Laurel It is does not seem to be related to the scoping change, as the problem is fixed by encapsulating the exponent in curly braces (which is probably good practice, anyway, but is neither here nor there).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm this behaviour on Math SE.  I am posting an answer so that I can share screenshots.  Note that curly braces solve the problem.

[image: this is how it renders in preview mode]

[image: and this is how it renders once submitted]

Comment: Interestingly, `\newcommand` does not give an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyKDW.png https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16302/4

Comment: Yes, `\def` also works...